# In the factory method pattern, Is it ok to abstract creator rather than interface it?

Tags: design-patterns

I'd like to periodically add attributes, but not have to alter the code for generating them anywhere else, so I've come up with the following which I believe is a factory method:

```
    //sudo code:
interace Attributes {  //should this be an abstract class instead?
   getFields();
       //possibly more items,
}

class RangeAttribute implements Attributes
{
    getFields()
    {
        return array('field1', 'field2');
    }
}
class MatchAttribute implements Attributes
{
    getFields()
    {
        return array('fieldA', 'field2', 'fieldB');
    }
}

class AttributeFactory {  // is this section the 'factory'
    public Attributes createAttribute(String type) {
    if (item.equals("Range")) {
        return new RangeAttribute();
    } else if (item.equals("Match")) {
        return new MatchAttribute();
    } else
        return null;
}



//main
AttributeFactory attrFact = new AttributeFactory();
Attributes attribute = attrFact.createAttribute(dropdown.selection);
foreach (str in attribute.getFields())
    print str; //more complex irl
```

First of all, is this a correct implementation of a factory method, and secondly, can I 
combine the factory method and a template method, for something similar to the following:

```
abstract class Attributes {  //should this be an abstract class instead?
abstract getFields();
//possibly more items,
renderFields() {
            foreach (str in attribute.getFields())
        print str; //more complex irl
       }
}
```

Is there a better pattern for this?  Can I take it further and have the abstract class Attributes extend another class (is it even ok to extend another class with an abstract class)?  Would it be better to have all the classes extend the same pattern?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a Factory, but it is not the Factory Method pattern.

For that you would have multiple factory classes which inherit from `AttributeFactory` (now abstract) and override `createAttribute`.

Then at runtime you can use the correct concrete factory.

It's not a replacement for what you have here, but hope that tells you the difference.

I would recommend you look at a dependency injection framework to resolve instances by a string name rather than repeated `if..then` blocks.

As for interfaces for the returned type, that's preferable. Always prefer interfaces to abstract classes. Maintaining class heirachies takes effort and restricts your options. Remember, composition over inheritence.

Comment: If I had multiple factory classes, wouldn't that be an abstract factory pattern? eg factory method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FactoryMethod.svg vs abstract factory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Abstract_factory.svg (these two similar patterns confuse me, but I thought abstract factory was for families of products)

Comment: They are very similar, but the wiki does say for abstract factory pattern: "a pattern often implemented using factory methods"

Comment: Guess you read the code samples on those pages as well as the diagrams. The car one is good on Factory Method, and I cant see how that doesn't fit abstract factory method pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try using enums in java. Sample factory for your demonstration

```
 public enum EnumButtonFactory {

RADIO(RadioButton.class),
SUBMIT(SubmitButton.class),
NORMAL(NormalButton.class);

private Class<? extends Button> button;

EnumButtonFactory(Class<? extends Button> b) {
    this.button = b;
}

public Button get() {
    try {
        return button.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Usage:

```
     button = EnumButtonFactory.NORMAL.get();
    button.click();
```